# How to use multiple Scanner objects on System.in in Java?

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

What's the correct way to use multiple Scanner objects in my program?

For example, I use the scanner to read a file, then depending on what is found in the file, I prompt for user input and use the scanner again.

Here is an extraction of my code:

```
Scanner f = new Scanner (System.in); // Get the file name
String fileName = f.next();

Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while (input.hasNext()) {
   String currentLine = input.nextLine();
   if (some pattern found) {
       Scanner getUserInput = new Scanner (System.in);
       String userInput = getUserInput.next();
       ...
   }
}
...
```

It doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to use `userInput.close()`?

What I don't understand is, the first `System.in` is just getting the file name. After that, why does it interfere with the second `System.in`?
As for the `input` object, it's reading from a file and not from `System.in`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Using multiple scanners on the same stream is the underlying problem. Scanners can (and will) consume the stream - this may (will) lead to unexpected side-effects. Best not to do it.

If the input is closed, then the input (but Strings have no `close` method) is closed for everyone - and that's not much fun for anyone.

**Edit:**
"Details" on why multiple scanners are bad:
[Do not create multiple buffered wrappers on a single byte or character stream](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream)

> ...any buffered wrapper is unsafe; this condition is also exploitable if a Scanner is used instead...

Comment: broken link looks like it should be --> https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream